# Expand protobuf message with subclass

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have two classes that I would like to transform to protobuf messages:

```
[ProtoContract]
class ClassA {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int b;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int c;
}

[ProtoContract]
class ClassD : ClassA
{
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public int e;
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public int f;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is a serialization of ClassA containing b and c. And when serializing ClassD i will get b, c, e and f.

Is this possible, or what kind of approach should I use? I'm trying to avoid nested messages.

Using my approach I get a problem when serializing a ClassD object.

```
ClassD d = new ClassD();
Serialize.Serialize<ClassA>(stream, d);
Serialize.Serialize<ClassD>(stream, d);
```

In both attempts above the serialized data only contain the properties in ClassD and none from ClassA.
I would expect at least none of the properties in ClassD to be serialized in the first case
and I would like all, both from ClassA and ClassD to be serialized in the second case.

How would I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this works in v2 *without* inheritance:

```
    var model = TypeModel.Create();
    model.Add(typeof(ClassA), false).Add("b", "c");
    model.Add(typeof(ClassD), false).Add("b", "c", "e", "f");

    var a = new ClassA { b = 1, c = 2 };
    var aClone = (ClassA)model.DeepClone(a);
    Debug.Assert(aClone.b == 1);
    Debug.Assert(aClone.c == 2);

    var d = new ClassD { b = 1, c = 2, e = 3, f = 4};
    var dClone = (ClassD)model.DeepClone(d);
    Debug.Assert(dClone.b == 1);
    Debug.Assert(dClone.c == 2);
    Debug.Assert(dClone.e == 3);
    Debug.Assert(dClone.f == 4);
```

These will each be flat models, not nested. At the moment this would need explicit setup (as above), as it isn't part of how it builds the model *by default* - but as a corollary you don't need attributes here:

```
class ClassA
{
    public int b;
    public int c;
}
class ClassD : ClassA
{
    public int e;
    public int f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
[ProtoContract, ProtoInclude(3, typeof(ClassD))]
class ClassA {...}
```

The "3" can be anything as long as it doesn't clash with anythig else from ClassA.

This *will* appear as a nested message on the wire, but automatically. If this is expressly *not* what you want, then let me know.

Comment: Yes this would work alone but would introduce a slightly different message layout. If there is no other way of doing it I am considering moving all properties into ClassA and marking the "ClassD" related ones as optional.

Comment: @phq I might be able to do it "as is" in v2; I'll look later - it won't work fork inheritance purposes though (I.e. If you send a D as an A, it'll deserialize as an A) - need to check